# NullReferenceException in Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I am using Repository pattern and  in my Repository.cs my _dataContext object returns null. What can I do so that it wont return null?

```
  private BlogDataContext _dataContext;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;
        private string[] _paths;

        public Repository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        {

                DataContext.Database.Log = Console.Write;
                DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
                _dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
        }

        protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        protected BlogDataContext DataContext
        {
            get { return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
        }
```

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: yes, DataContext is throwing an exception type of System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Are you using some kind of IOC framework? Ninject/Autofac/etc. Might be something that needs to be setup as injection?

Comment: Is `DatabaseFactory` null?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes it is null.

Comment: @thsorens I don't know, it isn't my code, I took it from somewhere and I'm editing.

Comment: When using repository pattern, its quite normal to inject the dbcontext. In your constructor, you see the that it puts in the IDatabaseFactory. This probably has to be injected, and bound to an implementation of IDatabaseFactory.

Comment: Simple. check why it is null. put a breakpoint in constructor and inspect parameter is null, if not see all the places where `DatabaseFactory` is written.

Answer (score 0):

The  main problem is that your `DatabaseFactory` property has a private setter, so you can't directly assign anything to it. So what you will do is to create a private `IDatabaseFactory` field, assign the constructor parameter *databaseFactory* to this field and return it in the getter of your `DatabaseFactory` property or make the `DatabaseFactory`  Property setter method public.

Comment: The DatabaseFactory can in fact be a readonly or with a private set, since it gets initiated trough the constructor.

Comment: I created the field : ` private IDatabaseFactory _databaseFactory;` In Repository I assigned `databaseFactory` to `_databaseFactory` and I changed `DatabaseFactory` property  so:
 `get { return _databaseFactory; } `
 `private set { DatabaseFactory = _databaseFactory; }` 
and my problem isn't solved. Did I a mistake?